# how to create no-reply mail?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

in my php-script I use phpmailer for sending e-mails, I entered the SMTP-logins and set "setFrom" no-reply@DOMAIN.de - but the message don't get sent, mail.log says :

```
Sender address rejected: not owned by user mail@DOMAIN.de; from=<no-reply@DOMAIN.de
```

so I have to create a user with the mail no-reply@ ... but I don't want that, its general that no-reply don't has a account. but how can I send mails with anything before the @ without adding this address ?

I already tried to remove the "reject_sender_login_mismatch" in the postfix config, but still this error.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What happens if you use `$mail->AddReplyTo` field for the senders address?